# Leanft not identifying terminal emulator screen objects

Tags: automated-tests, terminal-emulator, leanft

I am trying to spy the mainframe screen from leanft, but it is not identifying the individual fields. It is just identifying the whole screen and in the object identification center, it is showing as **Java.UiObject:Screen**.

I have registered the application in leanft still it is not able to identify.
I have done the TE configurator settings as well and I am able to inspect another mainframe application without any issues.

But this specific application is not getting identified.

Below is the code generated from the Object identification center for this application.

```
Desktop.describe(Window.class, new WindowDescription.Builder()
            .title("3 Host Session").build()).describe(UiObject.class, new UiObjectDescription.Builder()
            .nativeClass("com.ibm.eNetwork.beans.HOD.accessibility.AccessibleScreenText").build());
```

Please let me know if you have any solution for this issue.
Thanks

Comment: did you enable the TE in the engine?

Comment: yes it is enabled, i am able to automate the mainframe host screens. but this  mainframe screen is launching from a java application.

Comment: mainframe host screen is java probably. TE has it's own checkbox in engine configuration section

Comment: Hi Adelin, can you please help me in configuring the engine for this kind of application.

Comment: Follow [these steps](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/leanft/en/14.50-14.53/HelpCenter/Content/HowTo/TE_Addin_Overview.htm#mt-item-0)

Comment: Sorry, these steps are for general mainframe screens.

Comment: i am asking for Mainframe screen launching from a java application

Comment: They shouldn't be different. If you enable both technologies: java and TE, from the engine, you should be able to use spy to know exactly what you need to describe in your code

Answer (score 0):

This happens when either the TE configuration is not set or the add-in for the TE(terminal emulator) is not enabled. Follow the steps from below link to resolve the same:

https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uftdev/en/14.50-14.53/HelpCenter/Content/HowTo/TE_Addin_Overview.htm

Comment: Please, share steps here.